# Is it ok to ask for a mental model of x?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, not-constructive, rules

For example:

### Title

How can I grasp how different types of code interact; in a simple mental model?

### Body

You have many different higher level programming languages. Then you have operating system code and commands you can type into your shell. You have servers and databases. Some code that are binary and what not...

How can you grasp the interaction of all this code?

For example: can you view it all as code put into a command line; line after line with some languages put inside others, or what kind of mental model is useful for feeling like you have an understanding of what is going on?

Comment: Seems okay as long as I can answer that you can see the interactions as a [series of tubes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtOoQFa5ug8).  :-P  [Programmers Stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) fields questions more like this, but this still may be too open-ended.

Comment: @HostileFork - nope. Still too open-ended for Programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not on stack overflow.  The best way to do it is a matter of opinion, there's pretty much 1 way per programmer.  That makes it too open ended for this site.  Not an uninteresting question to talk about, but a bad one to talk about here.